# How to find char pattern offset in a String

Tags: java, regex

I have text file which has text with newline char like this. I read that text file into a String

```
random Text
State v. USA
some more text
USA v.
NY
Some more text
USA
v.LA ,  MN v. ND
USA vs. MN
```

I want to know offset (i.e. starting and ending char index) of patterns like **[Some word starting with cap] v. [Some word starting with cap]**

Or
**[Some word starting with cap] vs. [Some word starting with cap]**

For above example
"State v. USA" => **Start=11 and  End=22**

"USA v.
 NY"      => **Start=36 and End=45**

I started with something like this http://rubular.com/r/T7Ii2WDADw which is not covering all cases .

So, the program could return a Map where key is Start+","+End and value is actual text like "State v. USA"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cover both the cases you need to use this regex.

```
\w+\s((v.)|(vs.))\s\w+
```

In java code.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Testapp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
String text = "USA v. Russia \n Some other text \n India vs. Aus";
String regex="\\w+\\s((v.)|(vs.))\\s\\w+";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(text);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group()+ ":" +"start =" + matcher.start() + " end = " + matcher.end());
}
}
}
```

Output:

```
Starting & ending index ofUSA v. Russia:start=0 end = 13
Starting & ending index ofIndia vs. Aus:start=34 end = 47
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be a working regex: `\w+\s+vs?[.]\s+\w+`

Then, using `Matcher.find()`, you could get the beginning and end of each match using `Matcher.start(0)` and `Matcher.end(0)`.

Comment: Thanks! But, I just tested, and it doesn't cover the cases when there is newline. Please see here http://rubular.com/r/6xA0SBCLy0

Comment: you didn't indicate you wanted _any/multiple_ whitespace.  updated.

Comment: you example also includes "v.State".  if you intend to match that as well, change the `'\s+'` to `'\s*'`.

Comment: I thought my example illustrated any/multiple white spaces.Thanks for RegExp and java code, this is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Method `String.indexOf(String)` does exactly what you need.

Comment: I might have oversimplified the question to make you think indexOf() will work. I dont know actual finding string beforehead, please see in question, I am working on RegExp. I needed a solution using RegExp Find() or Matcher(). If you can, please elaborate how to find above mentioned pattern "USA v. State" offset  using String.indexOf(String). Thanks!

Comment: @S.Singh `int start = string.indexOf("USA v. State")` will give you the start `int end = start + "USA v. State".length()` will give you the end.

Comment: I don't know if it is "USA v. State" or something else. It could be Iraq v. USA or anything. Only thing I know it will contain "v." or "vs." Also, I need offset for ALL the occurrences, not just the first one. That is why I have mentioned about Map as return. Let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: @S.Singh Well, then you should have said so in your question ;)

Comment: @Baz My bad, I thought that would be obvious to RegExp experts when they see the rubular link :)